# Как при создании бд сразу добавлять её в SqliteStudio

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Возможно при создании таблицы добавлять её в SqliteStudio?

```
con = sqlite3.connect(f'{name_db}.db', check_same_thread=False)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
   name TEXT,
   url TEXT,
   price REAL,
   quantity TEXT,
   wear_category TEXT,
   sticker TEXT,
   sticker_price REAL);
   """)
con.commit()
```